# What is the most efficient way of joining tables of different dimensions?

Tags: sql, postgresql, kotlin, plpgsql

I have the following schema:

```
CREATE TABLE products (
  id                    BIGSERIAL NOT NULL,
  created_at_timestamp  TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW(),
  last_update_timestamp TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW(),
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE product_names (
  product_id BIGINT NOT NULL,
  language   TEXT   NOT NULL,
  name       TEXT   NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (product_id, language),
  FOREIGN KEY (product_id) REFERENCES products (id)
);

CREATE TABLE product_summaries (
  product_id BIGINT NOT NULL,
  language   TEXT   NOT NULL,
  summary    TEXT   NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (product_id, language),
  FOREIGN KEY (product_id) REFERENCES products (id)
);
```

And I want to `select` all Products.

However as you can see a Product contains a list of names and summaries (per language).

I can retrieve all Products

`SELECT * FROM products`

And then iterate all the rows (in this case in Kotlin), and then request the names and summaries:

`SELECT * FROM product_names WHERE product_id = $id`

And

`SELECT * FROM product_summaries WHERE product_id = $id`

However, this seems inefficient, since I am making 3 separate queries to the database.

I though of using `JOIN`s to get all of this with one query, but then I get multiple repeated rows for each `product_names` and `product_summaries` entry.

So in the end, is there a better way of requesting all this data in one query?

Comment: If you do not want multiple rows per product, what exactly do you want? If there's a summary per language, what data do you want exactly?

Comment: I'll might use json columns instead to store the names per language instead of tables. Any downside to this?

Comment: Definitely some downsides-- If you're querying only 1 language at a time, it'll be much faster to pull the data from a table indexed, ordered, or partitioned by language. In JSON, all the data will be lumped together in a (likely) external table where it'll have to jump to another table for every single row (internally anyway).. a relationship with 2 tables will be just as easy to  query, and likely faster. Plus, any updates will touch less blocks.

Comment: Can I query the names /summaries into a table in a subquery and return it as a column in the main select?

Comment: You can query all the results as a Jason field if necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You definitely don't want to do multiple queries and then iterate over them in the code.  That's horribly inefficient.  When you do the second `JOIN`, you need to include `language` in the `JOIN`.  That should keep you from getting duplicate rows.  This should give you **one** row for each unique combination of [products.id, product_names.language]

```
SELECT
    products.id
    ,products.created_at_timestamp
    ,products.last_update_timestamp
    ,product_names.name 
    ,product_summaries.summary
    ,product_names.language
FROM
    products
INNER JOIN
    product_names ON product_names.product_id = products.id
INNER JOIN
    product_summaries ON product_summaries.product_id = products.id 
    AND product_summaries.language = product_names.language
```

Comment: The issue is that I need to retrieve all languages at once, so it is like I need a table to be returned for each column 'name' and 'summary'.

Comment: Did you actually try *running* this query?  It **will** return all languages at once.  So the rows would look like: [id:1, name:englishName, summary:englishSummary, language:English], [id:1, name:spanishName, summary:spanishSummary, language:Spanish], [id:1, name:frenchName, summary:frenchSummary, language:French], [id:2, name:englishName, summary:englishSummary, language:English], [id:2, name:spanishName, summary:spanishSummary, language:Spanish], [id:2, name:frenchName, summary:frenchSummary, language:French]

Comment: Yes, but it returns one row per language, with the json aggregation I can end up with just one row per product id no matter how many languages. However it is probably the most efficient way for more generic situations so I'll mark this one as the answer.

Comment: OIC - your original question wasn't entirely clear to me.  Assuming that you have proper indexes on `products.id`, `product_names.product_id`, and `product_summaries.product_id`, the query above will perform very fast.  If you're worried about duplicate data coming back, you can further streamline it by removing the timestamps from the product.  If you stick to the idea of having only one row per product ID, that can theoretically work, but the deeper question is, "Where is this query being consumed?"  If it's being used in some block of code, that code is going to quickly become more complex

Comment: because that code will have to account for a varying number of columns.  Of course, if you're just trying to run the query and view the results in a query editor, then those concerns may not apply.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a way of doing it:

```
SELECT * FROM products as p INNER JOIN
(SELECT json_agg(product_names) as names, product_id FROM product_names GROUP BY product_id) as tb_names ON tb_names.product_id = p.id
INNER JOIN
(SELECT json_agg(product_summaries) as summaries, product_id FROM product_summaries GROUP BY product_id) as tb_summaries ON tb_summaries.product_id = p.id
```

returns:

`1  |   2018-07-20 09:36:21.56904   |   2018-07-20 09:36:21.56904   |   [{"product_id":1,"language":"EN","name":"lol"}, 
 {"product_id":1,"language":"DE","name":"lel"}]  |  1   [{"product_id":1,"language":"EN","summary":"deded"}, 
 {"product_id":1,"language":"DE","summary":"rererere"}, 
 {"product_id":1,"language":"FR","summary":"jejejeje"}]   |     1`

Basically I'm converting the multi-dimensional tables to JSON :)

Postgres is amazing!